# Values from firestore showing as undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a program that polls the weather every 30 seconds and I was getting CORS errors.  I investigated it and saw that the city and country were being read as undefined.

I get my user data from my users' table then send them with an Axios request to the weather API:

```
return axios({
    url: `https://europe-west1-hummid.cloudfunctions.net/api/weather`,
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        city: data?.city,
        country: data?.country
    },
    headers: {
        Authorization: `${authToken}`
    },
```

I have but they're being sent as undefined.  I currently have it set up using a useEffect to get the data from the users table

```
useEffect(() => {
    const userRef = db.collection('users').doc(currentUserEmail);
    userRef.get().then((doc) => {setData(toUser(doc));})
}, [currentUserEmail])
```

Then I pass it to a function that maps it to an interface:

```
export interface User {
    userId: string;
    fname: string;
    lname: string;
    country: string;
    city: string;
    email: string;
    phone: number;
}
export function toUser(doc: firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot): User {
    return {userId: doc.id, ...doc.data()} as User;
}
```

Is there a way to use my method of retrieving data or a better way to make sure I am not getting undefined values?  Also, is the reason I am getting undefined because I am using optional chaining on the values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you problem here is that you make your axios request before having data in your `data` state. Before making your request, you need to be sure that the state contains the data fetched from `userRef.get().then((doc) => {setData(toUser(doc));})`.

A simple way to achieve that is to put your axios request in a `useEffect` that listen changes on the `data` state and do the fetch when `data` is no more `undefined` or `null`:

```js
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      // Here fetch your API with data
      // It won't contain any undefined
      const { city, country } = data

      axios({
        url: `https://europe-west1-hummid.cloudfunctions.net/api/weather`,
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
          city,
          country
        }
      })
    }
  }, [data]);
```

Checkout the demo:

[image: Edit goofy-neumann-gvup0]